# calling methods on the result of an await

Tags: c#, async-await

I often want to write code like in `Compute1()`, but this doesn't compile as the object I am trying to perform the `ToHashset()` on is a `Task<string[]>`.

So I end up using the code in `Compute2()`

However, today I realised I could wrap the await in parentheses to do what I want.

Are there any hidden side effects with doing this? things to watch out for?

```
private async Task Compute1()
{
    // this won't compile as the result of the await is a Task
    HashSet<string> value = await GetValuesAsync().ToHashset();
}

private async Task Compute2()
{
    string[] value1 = await GetValuesAsync();
    HashSet<string> value2 = value1.ToHashSet();
}

private async Task Compute3()
{
    HashSet<string> value = (await GetValuesAsync()).ToHashSet();
}

private async Task<string[]> GetValuesAsync()
{
    // mock a long process that returns an array of strings
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    return new[] { "SomeValue" };
}
```

Comment: 2 and 3 are the same thing, just without making a variable. In fact, there's a good chance the compiler will remove the variable.

Comment: That is the intended way to do it, if you want to use a intermediate variable or not is just down to style or preference.. But as always with async/await and tasks, you need to be aware that there is a whole lot of magic going on behind the scene. While the compiler can make async code appear as if synchronous, there are some pitfalls to be aware of.

Comment: There's nothing specific to "watch out for" regarding this specific syntax, no.  The parentheses are simply how you wrap an expression to explicitly tell the compiler what you're awaiting.

Comment: No concerns in the syntax.  The parenthesis are needed to change the priorities of the operators (await has a lower priority than the `.`).

Comment: Adding `()` around this await should make the code compile if you don't want to use an intermediate variable: `HashSet<string> value = (await GetValuesAsync()).ToHashset();`

Comment: btw, there is a proposal to c# language, a bit stale one, to chain awaits: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/1117